# Extract bold value from cell in Microsoft Excel (2007)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet in which cells contain values one of which is bold. (It's a list of tickers, the bold one is the main ticker for the company.) I would like to extract the bold value from the cell.

[image]

Here is a link with sample data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz3ZKmiPPjmuNmY3MlRyZFRXa2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: unfortunately you can't reach formatting information with standard functions in Excel, you need to use VBA for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Function findBold(ByVal rngText As Range) As String
    findBold = ""
    Dim theCell As Range
    Set theCell = rngText.Cells(1, 1)
    For i = 1 To Len(theCell.Value)
        If theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then
            theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
            Results = Results & theChar
        End If
   Next i
   findBold = Results
End Function
```

If your data is in cell *A1* then you have to put on cell *B1* the formula `=findBold(A1)`.